# How to redirect to a different route in Blazor Server-side

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side

In Blazor Client a redirection can be achieved using

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Browser.Services;
(...)
BrowserUriHelper.Instance.NavigateTo("/route")
```

This does however not work in a Blazor Server project, as it generates the following error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Server.Circuits.RemoteJSRuntime' to type 'Microsoft.JSInterop.IJSInProcessRuntime'.

How does a redirect in Blazor-Server look like?

Comment: Question, why are you redirecting on the server to another controller?  Can you not simply execute you desired method?  Rather than route to a new HttpContext?  Otherwise you would need to render a partial view and pass it back as some form of accessible data that can be rendered again.

Comment: So when you create a Server-side project, you get server and client projects. I want to do this in client app in razor page. When user clicks on a button, a request goes to the server, and depending on the response, I want to either redirect to a different page or stay on current.

Comment: Yeah, but when the client hits the event to navigate within the client, you trigger the server side event from the client.  The client applications navigates based on the response the server gives it.  Then the client will utilize the proper component view based on the response provided by the server.

Comment: So the server has to actually tell the client to navigate to a different page? So how that can be achieved for my scenario? Do you know if there is an example?

Comment: For non server side hosted Blazor implementations, yes.  For Blazor, not at the moment I would have to play with it.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

If you can trigger on the razor page, you can use the following:

```
@page "/YourPageName"
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<h1>xxx</h1>
.
.
.


@code {

    void MethodToTriggerUrl()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("PageToRedirect");
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of MethodToTriggerUrl() which of course won't be called automagically, you can put  NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/PageToRedirect"); into protected override void OnInitialized(){} which will trigger automatic redirection.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it's totally up to your design. If you want to redirect automatically, you can do that. You can even put some count down and redirect afterwards. The question's answer is just `NavigationManager.NavigateTo()` :)

Answer (score 10):

After time and time of experimenting, I found out that in server side this is working:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Services;
(...)
UriHelper.NavigateTo("/route");
```

Granted, looks almost the same, but does the work (at least in Blazor 0.8)

Comment: In 0.9, for me at least, I needed to @inject IUriHelper UriHelper

Comment: **UriHelper** has been renamed to **NavigationManager** in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components namespace: 
`@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager; NavigationManager.NavigateTo("route", false);`

Comment: I have a Blazor server app that needs to redirect to pages in a separate Blazor component library and `NavigationManager` is useless. For some reason it doesn't get initialized, I have no way to navigate from a page in the server project to a page in the library project.

Comment: For some reason Microsoft loves to break backwards compatibility because for me the UriHelper class is in a different namespace and it doesn't have that method, and the namespace you mentioned doesn't even exist for me in .NET 8.0, and your answer was just 5 years ago.

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly what you're looking for, but "a solution" nonetheless.  I can't seem to find a way presently, to do something similar to Response.Redirect on the server-side, but using jsinterop,  in the component you wish to be able to redirect FROM, use something like this.  Note, I was curious also, and knowing this would come up for myself also, I did the following:

So based on the sample app with the server-side project template...

index.cshtml

```
@using Microsoft.JSInterop;

 <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="@GoSomewhere">Go somewhere with Blazor</a>

@functions {
    protected void GoSomewhere()
    {
        RedirectTo("/FetchData");  //or any other "page" in your pages folder
    }

    public static Task<string> RedirectTo(string path)
    {
        return JSRuntime.Current.InvokeAsync<string>(
            "clientJsfunctions.RedirectTo", path);
    }    
}
```

then, under the wwwwroot folder, place a javascript file with this:

```
window.clientJsfunctions = {       
    RedirectTo: function (path) {
        window.location = path;
    }
};
```

Finally, in your bootstrapper file, index.html, place a refeference to this js file

```
<body>
    <app>Loading...</app>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts/ClientUtil.js"></script>
</body>
```

Even better, place methods such as the one above "RedirectTo" in a seperate class, and use this as a base class for most of your component pages.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Components;
using Microsoft.JSInterop;

namespace MyApp.Web.App.Shared
{
    public class MycomponentBase : BlazorComponent
    {
        public static Task<string> RedirectTo(string path)
        {
            return JSRuntime.Current.InvokeAsync<string>(
                "clientJsfunctions.RedirectTo", path);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, remember to put this at the top of each component 
@inherits MycomponentBase;

Now, you should have a "Redirect" method you can call from any component that derives from your base component class.